# Divided Differences expanded form definition.

Tags: derivatives, interpolation, recursive-algorithms

From definition of divided differences we have that $$f[x_0,\cdots,x_n]=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{f(x_j)}{\Pi_{{k\in\{0,\cdots,n\}-\{j\}}}(x_j-x_k)} $$
It makes completely sense to have $k\neq j$ otherwise the denominator becomes zero.
In many articles I've seen the following notation,
let $q(\xi)=(\xi -x_0)\cdots(\xi-x_n)$, then we can re-express the expanded form of the divided difference as
$$f[x_0,\cdots,x_n]=\sum_{j=0}^n\frac{f(x_j)}{q'(x_j)}$$

In [this](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DividedDifference.html) link there's a brief explanation but I don't really get the point.
why is it that $$q'(x_j)=(x_j - x_0)\cdots(x_j -x_{j-1})(x_j-x_{j+1})\cdots(x_j - x_n)$$ ?
Maybe I am messing up things, but if I apply the product rule for derivatives I don't obtain that result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Note that $q'$ is being computed at point $x_j$... All the other terms that you obtain deriving the product have a factor $(x-x_j)$ that vanishes when $x=x_j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, look at the following equivalent expression of $q$:
$$q(\xi)=(\xi-x_j)\cdot \prod_{i\neq j}{(\xi - x_i)}$$
Take the derivative of $q(\xi)$ with respect to $\xi$, using the product rule (no need to expand the rightmost expression):
$$q'(\xi)=1\cdot \prod_{i\neq j}{(\xi - x_i)} + (\xi-x_j)\cdot \left( \prod_{i\neq j}{(\xi - x_i)}\right )'$$
Now substitute $\xi=x_j$, to get
$$q'(x_j)=\prod_{i\neq j}{(x_j - x_i)} + (x_j-x_j)\cdot \left( \prod_{i\neq j}{(x_j - x_i)}\right )' = \prod_{i\neq j}{(x_j - x_i)}$$

I don't think you should view it as anything more meaningful than a shorthand for the longer expression on the right hand side.